# PhotoImage problem - images are not appear -Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

```
from tkinter import *
import webview
app = Tk()
app.title('Mariam_web_browser')
app.geometry('1200x700+200+10')
app.config(bg='white')

my_img=PhotoImage(r'Images\profile.png')
my_img_lbl=Label(app,image=my_img,width=200,height=200)
my_img_lbl.place(x=600,y=300)

app.mainloop()
```

#this is my code to add an image on my window
#it doesn't give error but the image doesn't appear....why?
**   # note: Images is the images folder inside my project folder.
**     # profile.png is my image file.
# I use pycharm .'''

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: PhotoImage(file='Images\profile.png')

Comment: What's the error though?